# To compute the volume and the lateral area of a $3D$ tube with non-uniform section whose axis is a spatial line $L$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, solid-geometry, solid-of-revolution

What's the way to compute the volume and the lateral area of a $3D$ tube with non-uniform section whose axis is a spatial line $L$? And what's the mathematical name of this geometry in the first place?
[image]

Comment: "Tube" seems like a pretty good description. The volume will be the integral of the areas of the cross-sections. How familiar are you with calculus?

Comment: Hi welcome to MathSE. What you are asking is just too wide. I think it's impossible to guess a name for a geometry that you show in the image. You could compute such volumes given parametric equation of the surface but like this it's impossible to answer